# canvas change file api for local storage

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm working with canvas and I have a script that uploads an image from user desktop and I need to change it to load images from the same page and put them on canvas (uploaded files from desktop go directly to canvas already).

the functions:

```
window.onload=function(){
  var s = document.getElementById("fontsize");
  s.value="48";
  document.getElementById('loadpicture').addEventListener('change', aFileIsLoaded, false);
  backgroundimagemode=NONE;
  carpeInit();
  update();
}
```

and:

```
function aFileIsLoaded(e1)
{
        var filename = e1.target.files[0];
        var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function(e2)
    {
          backgroundimage = new Image();
          backgroundimage.src=e2.target.result;
    };
        fr.readAsDataURL(filename);
}
```

Thank you

It's my first question here, I think I wrote before in the wrong box, sorry

I have now this code as you suggested

```
function aFileIsLoaded(e1)
{
        var filename = e1.target.files[0];
        var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function(e2)
    {
          backgroundimage = new Image();
          backgroundimage.src=e2.target.result;
         var context = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');
         context.canvas.width = backgroundimage.width;
         context.canvas.height = backgroundimage.height;
         context.drawImage(backgroundimage, 0, 0, backgroundimage.width, backgroundimage.height);


    };
        fr.readAsDataURL(filename);
}
```

before, the image was loaded from desktop with

```
<input type="file" name="backpicture" id="loadpicture">
```

How can I call now from a list of images?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a canvas in the document with the id `myCanvas` you can add this to the `fr.onload` function you have now.

```
var context = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');

context.canvas.width = backgroundimage.width;
context.canvas.height = backgroundimage.height;

context.drawImage(backgroundimage, 0, 0, backgroundimage.width, backgroundimage.height);
```

wow, very fast, thank you
in this way without deleting anythin?

```
function aFileIsLoaded(e1)
{
        var filename = e1.target.files[0];
        var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function(e2)
   {

var context = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');
context.canvas.width = backgroundimage.width;
context.canvas.height = backgroundimage.height;
context.drawImage(backgroundimage, 0, 0, backgroundimage.width, backgroundimage.height);
          backgroundimage = new Image();
          backgroundimage.src=e2.target.result;
    };
        fr.readAsDataURL(filename);
}
```

Comment: in this way? without removing anything?  function aFileIsLoaded(e1)
{
        var filename = e1.target.files[0];
        var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function(e2)
    {

var context = document.getElementById('canvaslogo').getContext('2d');

context.canvas.width = backgroundimage.width;
context.canvas.height = backgroundimage.height;

context.drawImage(backgroundimage, 0, 0, backgroundimage.width, backgroundimage.height);





          backgroundimage = new Image();
          backgroundimage.src=e2.target.result;
    };
        fr.readAsDataURL(filename);
}

Comment: Add the code in my answer at the *end* of the `fr.onload` function. You added it before.